# How to Recover My Windows 7 files

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, system-installation, data-recovery

Unfortunately i did replace windows7 with ubuntu os . my hard drive is formatted please help me any one to recovery my files

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is almost impossible. The hard disk has a new FS (Linux's `ext4`) and the data has probably been overwritten by Ubuntu's data.

**If it's really important data you should shut down the computer ASAP as every time you write data the chance on recovery decreases.**

You could try a few recovery tools (try them while using Ubuntu live on a USB drive to prevent writing to the disk) but I don't think they'll work because you're using a different FS now.

Your best bet would be to bring the hard disk to a data recocery company but this can be really expensive.

So next time be careful what you're doing when partitioning and **always** make backups.